# SQL Select rows with column values that match column values in different table

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I have Table A that contains columns 'CustomerID' and 'MONTH', as well as a column 'PRODUCT' which is always the same e.g. **Product X**

I also have Table B that contains columns 'CustomerID' and 'MONTH' but this table includes lots of products, not just X.

I am trying to select rows from Table B (lots of products) whose 'CustomerID' AND 'MONTH' match a row in Table A, so that I end up with products that a customer bought in the same month  as they bought **Product X**

I have tried the following:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE DATA.RESULT AS
   SELECT LOTS.Customer_ID, 
          LOTS.Product_Name, 
          LOTS.Order_Revenue, 
          LOTS.Month_Ordered
   FROM DATA.Family_Holiday_Orders_Plus AS LOTS
   INNER JOIN DATA.X AS X1 ON (X1.Customer_ID = LOTS.Customer_ID)
   INNER JOIN DATA.X AS X2 ON (X2.Month_Ordered = LOTS.Month_Ordered);
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to select all products from `LOTS` where another row in `DATA.X` with the same `Customer_ID` and `Month_Ordered`
value exists.

```
SELECT LOTS.Customer_ID, 
       LOTS.Product_Name, 
       LOTS.Order_Revenue, 
       LOTS.Month_Ordered
FROM DATA.Family_Holiday_Orders_Plus AS LOTS
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM DATA.X AS X1 WHERE X1.Customer_ID = LOTS.Customer_ID
    AND X1.Month_Ordered = LOTS.Month_Ordered
)
```